# Simple queries running for a very long time

Tags: postgresql

I have an Amazon RDS instance running PostgreSQL 9.3 behind a pgbouncer 14.2 instance running in session pooling mode servicing a PHP Codeigniter application running on top of nginx.

For the last couple of weeks it seems that DB connections slowly accumulate until the max number of connections is reached and makes it impossible to run queries against the DB forcing us to restart the pgbouncer (thus aborting connections).

After looking at logs for both pgbouncer and nginx and also at the RDS monitoring I decided to check the DB and found out some queries are running for hours for no discernible reason.

Currently I have a very simple query running for over 4 hours:

```
SELECT json_cache 
FROM cache 
WHERE id='27325' 
AND passengers_id = '26817'`
```

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cache 
(
id bigserial NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('cache_id_seq'::regclass),
passengers_id int8 NOT NULL,
created_on timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT 'now()',
json_cache text(2147483647),
isr_xml text(2147483647),
passengers_route_history_id int8,
CONSTRAINT pk_cache PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX pk_cache ON cache (id);
```

This is the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output:

```
Index Scan using pk_cache on cache
(cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=724) (actual time=0.033..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
Index Cond: (id = 27325)
Filter: (passengers_id = 26817)
Total runtime: 0.074 ms
(4 rows)
```

The table has a little under 30k rows and the query simple so I can't figure out why it's taking so long.

It's also not the only query taking this long, there are two other simple queries running for several hours now and none of them seem to be waiting on a lock according to the info in pg_stat_activity.

This is my first time asking a DB related question on SO and I'm actually not very familiar with PostgreSQL so if there's anything I'm missing (in info given and at all) please let me know.

Comment: Is there something locking your table ?

Comment: Explain analyze says total runtime is: 0.074 **milli** seconds. That's the runtime on the server. So the query itself is blazingly fast. There must be something else going on.

Comment: I will look into other parts of my infrastructure again and update if I find anything odd, thanks.